# Gradient color for text of QLabel Qt/c++

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I trying to set gradient color for QLabel text. I am trying to use setStyleSheet function but it doesn't work. I [read this article](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32781-don-t-work-qlineargradient-for-text-in-QLabel) but still can't get the working solution.

this is my code

```
void MyClass::setTitle(const QString& text)
{
    m_text = text;
    m_titleText->setText(text);
    QFont font = m_titleText->font();
    font.setPointSize(12);
    m_titleText->setFont(font);
    m_titleText->setStyleSheet("color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0,    x2: 0, y2: 1,    #3d5afe: 0 #66e, stop: 1 #fd3e7f);")
}
```

Is there any solution for this problem?
Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
   void MyClass::setTitle(const QString& text)
    {
        m_text = text;
        m_titleText->setText(text);
        QFont font = m_titleText->font();
        font.setPointSize(12);
        m_titleText->setFont(font);
        QPalette labelPal;
        QLinearGradient colorGradient = QLinearGradient(0, 0, m_titleText->width(), 0);
        colorGradient.setSpread(QGradient::RepeatSpread);
        colorGradient.setColorAt(0, QColor("#3d5afe"));
        colorGradient.setColorAt(1, QColor("#fd3e7f"));
        QBrush brush(colorGradient);
        labelPal.setBrush(QPalette::ColorRole::Text, brush);
    
        m_titleText->setPalette(labelPal);
        m_titleText->setForegroundRole(QPalette::Text);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man, it's awesome, I tried it and its working.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an invalid syntax, but the QSS parser is not able to determine that (or, at least, doesn't give any warning about it), so it just ignores the gradient and uses the default palette color for text.
The problem is that you're missing a `stop` definition and used a color instead.

Change to:

```
    m_titleText->setStyleSheet("color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0,    x2: 0, y2: 1,    stop: 0 #66e, stop: 1 #fd3e7f);")
```

Note that the same could also be done using a QPalette with a QLinearGradient (with object bounding mode) set as brush for the `WindowText` role.

Answer (score -1):

```
 ui->label->setStyleSheet(
    "* {color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0 y1:0, x2:1 y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));"
    "background: qlineargradient( x1:0 y1:0, x2:1 y2:0, stop:0 cyan, stop:1 blue);}");
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, In image I see gradient color for background but not for text. Your start color of gradient is black, but I didn't see black color in text. I had same problem, text color is always end color of gradient.